# Making a pronoun verb reflexive of its subject

Tags: reflexivos

In place of

> Apago las luces.

we may make the verb reflexive of its subject and say

> Las luces se apagan.

in order to emphasize the object instead of the subject.

Some verbs already are pronoun verbs such as *sentirse* or *referirse*.

In this case, if we have the sentence

> Para estar alegre, uno necesita sentirse seguro.

but we want to make the verb reflexive in its subject, should we write

> Para estar alegre, se necesita sentirse seguro.

or

> Para estar alegre, se necesita sentir seguro.

or something else?

Comment: You're misusing "alegre" the tiniest bit here -- FYI.  "Contento" would fit better.  Feeling safe leads us to being "contento" but "alegre" is more like "cheerful."  For me, at least, it takes a little more than a feeling of safety to get to "alegre."

Answer (score 3):

Your first consideration:

*In place of: "Apago las luces," we may make the verb reflexive of its subject and say: "Las luces se apagan" in order to emphasize the object instead of the subject.*

is not accurate.

Although the passive voice can be formed with the particle "se," the passive meaning is not always present when "se" is there. In fact, *apagarse* can be understood as a pronominal verb used to indicate that the action takes place without the necessary participation of an agent (perhaps the lights go out automatically when the day breaks, or because there is a blackout, and not necessarily because somebody turns them off).

"sentirse" and "referirse" are clearly pronominal. Now, your sentences:

> (1) *Para estar alegre, se necesita sentirse seguro.
>
> (2) *Para estar alegre, se necesita sentir seguro.

are ungrammatical because you cannot use a pronominal verb after an impersonal one (sentence 1 above) and because "sentirse" **needs** to be pronominal to make sense in this case (sentence 2 above), so some other alternative has to be found if you want to do away with "uno" and make the sentence impersonal:

- Para estar alegre, **es necesario** sentirse seguro.
- Para estar alegre, **se necesita** sentir seguridad. (less idiomatic, less natural than the former, but equally correct)

In the book "[Valores gramaticales de *se*](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=BG0GQqBL3OQC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22dos%20verbos%20pronominales%22&source=bl&ots=doc9FtAa-7&sig=tmxUEsXKbtaG7KNQ_syUvr13CZY&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHg-_J_NXZAhWyrFkKHVStC7YQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22dos%20verbos%20pronominales%22&f=false)" by Leonardo Gómez Torrego we can find this interesting reference to the coexistence of two pronominal verbs:

[image: Dos verbos pronominales seguidos]

We can observe that this phenomenon is possible because both verbs, the finite and the nonfinite one, **share the same subject**. Another case in which this coexistence of pronominal verbs is possible occurs when one of them is passive and an indirect object (which functions as the tacit subject of the infinitive) is implicit:

- **Se** recomienda quedar**se** sentado. (Staying seated is recommended.)
  (This can also be understood as: Se recomienda **a la gente** quedarse sentada, where "la gente" is the subject of "quedarse sentada").

However, it is ungrammatical to have two pronominal verbs in a sequence when the first one (A) is impersonal or (B) is in a passive form that does not allow for a tacit indirect object:

(A)

- *Se necesita quedarse sentado. (incorrect)
- *Se puede quedarse parado. (incorrect)
- *Se debe quedarse quieto. (incorrect)

Instead, one has to say:

- Es necesario quedarse sentado / Uno tiene que quedarse sentado.
- Es posible quedarse parado / Uno puede quedarse parado.
- Es obligatorio quedarse quieto / Uno debe quedarse quieto.

(B)

- *Se abolió vestirse de luto. (incorrect)

BUT:

- Se prohibió (a la gente) vestirse de luto. (correct)
- Se autorizó (a la gente) vestirse de luto. (correct)
- Se exige (a la gente) vestirse de luto. (correct)
- Se permite (a la gente) vestirse de luto. (correct)
- Se requiere (a la gente) vestirse de luto. (correct)

Comment: A pesar de que formalmente «se necesita sentirse seguro» esté incorrecto, también sería de notar que es una estructura que sí se emplea incluso en textos formales (sobre todo con otros verbos empleados comúnmente en impersonal, como *se puede*, *se recomienda*, etcétera).  Formalmente, a mí solo me gusta la primera opción, porque no sabemos si sentimos seguridad o si nos sentimos seguridad (ahora bien, con este verbo no creo que haya problemas, pero con otros puede haber más diferencia entre el significado normal y pronominal)

Comment: @guifa Se puede utilizar un verbo pronominal después de "se recomienda" porque es pasivo: *Se recomienda quedarse sentado = Quedarse sentado es/está recomendado.* Sinceramente no veo que ese tipo de construcciones, con dos verbos con "se", pueda utilizarse con "se puede" o "se necesita", que forman perífrasis modales y no tienen sentido pasivo sino impersonal.

Comment: es incorrecto tener dos verbos reflexivos juntos?

Comment: @Erin Es mejor hablar de verbos pronominales. Los reflexivos son apenas un tipo de verbos pronominales. Mi afirmación es que sólo se pueden usar dos verbos pronominales juntos (donde uno está subordinado al otro) cuando el subordinante comparte el mismo sujeto que el subordinado (*Se obstina en quedarse*) o cuando el subordinante está en una forma pasiva que acepta complemento directo (*Se permite quedarse hasta la noche* -- Se permite **a la gente** quedarse hasta la noche).

Comment: @Erin Cuando esté disponible, lee esta página: http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Verbos%20pronominales.htm

Comment: @walen Creo que tienes razón. Sería similar a "se requiere". Esta pregunta ha tocado un tema sobre el cual no hay mucha bibliografìa, y creo que entre los hablantes podemos llegar a algunas conclusiones. Ahora, "se necesita sentirse seguro" me suena, ni no agramatical, muy dudosa.

Comment: Que interesante discusión para una pregunta aparentemente tan simple :-) @walen el contexto si está y es **Para estar alegre...**  ¿en este caso que opinas? ¿es la correcta o la incorrecta?. A mi me suena bien.

Comment: Por todo lo de arriba es porque escribí que a pesar de ser formalmente incorrecto, se escucha jaja.  No creo haberlo visto en el español áurico o medieval, pero voy a estar más atento a ello.  No veo razón per se que no se pueda con verbo impersonal —aparte de que no se hacía—, y puede que estemos viendo una evolución que queda un poco en, como dice walen, una zona dudosa.

Comment: @walen "Me necesito sentir seguro" suena muy raro. Para mí es incorrecto. La transitividad de "necesitar" nos lleva a preguntarnos: *¿Qué necesito?* y a responder: *Necesito sentirme seguro.* Con otros verbos, el pronombre antepuesto funciona bien: *Me tengo que sentir seguro / Me debo sentir seguro.*